# Force SMTP relay to use specific server

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, smtp

Is there a way to tell IIS to us another SMTP relay?

Something like this?

```
Application(s) sends email SMTP relay on server A.
Server A sends email to SMTP realy on server B.
Server B send mail to recipient.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a gateway to send all remote mails. But i don't think you can set it "by application". So all mails from all applications on server A will be send to server B. As i understand, recipient is not on server B, so Server B need to accept mails from server A that are not for Server B (relaying)

On server B, change relay restriction:
[Microsoft Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/58f05ef9-55a3-42b3-9f57-27fdc8723b8a.mspx?mfr=true)